# Customize Ecto Repo

Tags: elixir, ecto

In functional programming, you can always add another layer of abstraction by having functions call other functions. We currently have the our repo available as `ZB.Repo`. The idea is that we could replace this module with `SpecialRepo` and add  modify/augment what happens when you interact with the repo.

Unfortunately, some features of Ecto, like associations especially, call the repo functions for you. And, in fact, in Ecto 3, they don't call the repo functions at all. They interact with the database directly bypassing your repo entirely. (`on_delete: :delete_all`)

This seems very limiting and doesn't work for us. Is there no way to get in between the application and the repo when using Ecto?

Comment: We need a more concrete example to help. Yes, Ecto doesn't have hooks/callbacks. They are considered a bad practice and business logic should be explicit. If you describe what exactly did you want to achieve by "getting in between application and the repo", we can think of an alternate solution. If there is more than one problem, you can consider asking multiple questions.